# Como detectar e calcular o ângulo de um objeto dentro de uma imagem em python?

Tags: python, matemática, processamento-de-imagens, triângulo

Estou tentando escrever um código que detecte as linhas e calcule um ângulo dentro de uma imagem binária (não necessariamente essa, mas sempre um spray semelhante). Eu li algumas coisas sobre transformada de Hough e até produto escalar, mas não consigo aplica-los.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por enquanto eu tenho esse código apenas:

```
import cv2 
import numpy as np  
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img_grey = cv2.imread('sprayang.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
img = cv2.GaussianBlur (img_grey, (5,5), 0)

th = 0
max_val = 255

    ret, o1 = cv2.threshold(img, th, max_val, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU )
```

Que me gera essa imagem:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Usando a ferramenta de ângulo do ImageJ, nessa imagem, li 90°.

Comment: qual é a dúvida?

Comment: Preciso, em python, detectar um ângulo de abertura em uma imagem (um spray, como esse do exemplo) e calcula-lo.

Comment: a ferramenta de angulo do ImageJ não serve?

Comment: Sim, Flavio. Mas eu gostaria de criar algo para detectar e calcular o ângulo sem a necessidade de criar os pontos manuais para identificar as linhas. Basicamente, abrir o arquivo, run e resultado em °.